# C++ Pointer GUI QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, pointers

I could be barking up the wrong tree completely with this, but it does compile, it just crashes. I'm only doing C++ the last 2 weeks, coming from mainly a Java background, which isn't exactly extensive!!

Anywho, I have a Room class. I want to set 4 exits, North, South, East, West. I had the idea to create a setExits() method that takes 4 Room pointers. Each Room object has a goNorth() etc method that calls that pointer.

```
Room::Room(QString name, QString shortD, QString longD, QImage roomImage)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->shortD = shortD;
    this->longD = longD;
    this->roomImage = roomImage;
}

QString Room::shortDescription()
{
    return shortD;
}

QString Room::longDescription()
{
    return longD;
}

QImage Room::showImage()
{
    return roomImage;
}

void Room::setExits(Room *north, Room *south, Room *east, Room *west)
{
    this->north = north;
    this->south = south;
    this->east = east;
    this->west = west;
}

Room* Room::goNorth()
{
    return north;
}
```

I am calling and setting it up like this.

```
void TheIslandMain::createRooms()
{
    //Room *forest, *lake; - declare as global in theislandmain.h?
    forest = new Room(readRooms("../Island/Rooms/forest.name"), readRooms("../Island/Rooms/forest.short"), readRooms("../Island/Rooms/forest.long"), getImage("../Island/Rooms/forest.jpg"));
    //forest->setExits(lake, currentRoom, currentRoom, currentRoom);

    lake = new Room(readRooms("../Island/Rooms/lake.name"), readRooms("../Island/Rooms/lake.short"), readRooms("../Island/Rooms/lake.long"), getImage("../Island/Rooms/lake.jpg"));
    currentRoom = forest;
}
```

When a button in the gui is clicked, I am using the following code.

```
void TheIslandMain::on_northButton_clicked()
{
    ui->roomDesc->clear();
    currentRoom = lake;
    //currentRoom = currentRoom->goNorth();
    ui->actionLabel->setText(currentRoom->shortDescription());
    ui->imageArea->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(currentRoom->showImage()));
}
```

I have commented out the code I want to use, that is giving the error. The code as it is now works fine. When I uncomment the code, again, it compiles file but I get a 255 error once I click on the North button and it crashes.

I'm not even sure if this is a legal thing to do, it's just something I was thinking about. Am I barking up the wrong tree completely? Like I said, I'm only learning C++ and we haven't actually done anything on pointers in class yet.

My understanding of the commented code is that I am changing the memory reference of the currentRoom variable to the reference north that is in the Room object, which itself is taken from a reference defined in the main class.

Sorry if I'm being stupid!

Comment: What is `lake`?  Also, it's customary to put some sort prefix or suffix on class member variables, so you don't have to `this->` everywhere when you have args named the same (usually in constructors).

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that. I currently have two Room objects set up, forest and lake. Going North from forest, which is the default currentRoom, leads to lake.

That's the way we were shown (regarding this->) - baby steps, I assume since we are coming from Java! :)

Comment: You're not calling `setExits` in the (non-commented) code you posted, and the commented code that does looks suspicious (references currentRoom before you assign to that).

Comment: setExits would only be called when setting up the Room. The currentRoom though could be the problem. That makes sense, I initially had null in there. That's something to think on

Comment: Same for the lake parameter in fact.

Comment: I should point out also that Room *forest and Room *lake are declared in the main and not in the actual function createRooms()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `//forest->setExits(lake, currentRoom, currentRoom, currentRoom);` will obviously cause problems if you uncomment it, because `lake` is not initialized.

Comment: That seemed to have fixed it! Glad to see that I had the right idea at least with pointers. I see where I messed up, I just need to be less stupid, couldn't see the forest for the trees!